# Get remote branches for git URL without local git

Tags: git

Is there a git command that returns a list of remote branches given remote git repository URL?

It doesn't make sense that I need to set up local git repository just for listing all remote branches!

Thanks!

Comment: If `fetch origin` doesn't do it, probably no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the output of [`git ls-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote)

```
 git ls-remote /urL/of/repo
```

> Displays references available in a remote repository along with the associated commit IDs.

Amongst the references listed, you will find `refs/heads/xxx`, with the names of the branches.

You will find also the tags, and the current HEAD.

You don't need a local repo to execute that command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git branch` for local branches and `git branch -r` for remote branches. Before you have to fetch the branches with `git fetch origin`.

With that command you get all new branch informations.

Comment: That's a good solution but I wanted something that will do it without having to init local git repository and fetch anything. The solution of @VonC is exactly it. Thanks!