# Get list of git repo branch names

Tags: git, shell, scripting, jenkins-pipeline

How do I get a list of branch names from a git repository in a shell script?

e.g. If my repo has the following branches:

```
master, dev, test, feature/new-feature
```

I want to store these in a list that can be accessed to check if a a certain branch name exists already. I then can use this command(s) in a script for use in a Jenkinsfile

Thanks

Comment: `def branchList = sh(script: 'git branch -r', returnStdout: true).readLines()`

Comment: @yong `git branch -r` lists only **remote** branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) — without options it lists all local branches, with option `-r` remote branches, with `-a` all (local + remote combined).

But the command is not intended to be used in shell scripts. The most correct way is to use [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref):

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/
```

to list local branches;

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/remotes/
```

to list remote branches;

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/tags/
```

to list tags;

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/
```

to list all references (local branches + remote branches + tags).

Comment: Thanks @phd, this is helpful. Do you know if it is possible to run this same command for a different repo by specifying the url of that repo? Thanks

Comment: @hs14428 The same? No. Git is intended mostly for local operations. There is though one command that can list branches and tags by URL: [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote). Run `git ls-remote --heads URL` to get the list of branches. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24655383/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+branches+remote+URL

Comment: Ah yes, that is also very helpful, thanks